# Unable to get the exact element class table when scraping data from web using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to scrape below table from the website.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWDkT.png)

Based on the web code I found that the table seemed belongs to element class `etxtmed` so I wrote below VBA. After running this code I found that it only scrape below data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxoPH.png)

I thought this was because `("etxtmed")(0)` refers to the 1st `("etxtmed")` table then I tried several numbers after `(0)` and VBA first reports `"Element not exist"` then reports error `Run-time error '91':Object variable or With block variable not set` at this line of code `r = tbl.Rows.Length - 1`. Is it because I scraped the wrong class of table?

```
Sub CopyRateFromHKAB()

    Dim ie As Object, btnmore As Object, tbl As Object
    Dim rr As Object, cc As Object, r As Integer, c As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Clear
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ie
        '.Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.hkab.org.hk/DisplayInterestSettlementRatesAction.do?lang=en"
        
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop While .readyState <> 4 Or .Busy
          
    
        Set tbl = .document.getElementsByClassName("etxtmed")(0)
        
        If tbl Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Element not exist"
        End If
            
    End With
    
    'get data from table
    r = tbl.Rows.Length - 1
    c = tbl.Rows(0).Cells.Length - 1
    
    ReDim arr(0 To r, 0 To c)
    
    Set rr = tbl.Rows
    For i = 0 To r
        Set cc = rr(i).Cells
        For j = 0 To c
            arr(i, j) = cc(j).innertext
        Next
    
    Next
    
    ie.Quit
  
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Resize(r + 1, c + 1) = arr
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .UsedRange.WrapText = False
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you want is inside an IFRAME so you need to access that page directly `<iframe src="/hibor/listRates.do?lang=en&Submit=Detail"`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRateFromHKAB()
    
    Const URL = "https://www.hkab.org.hk/hibor/listRates.do?lang=en&amp;Submit=Detail"
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object, request As Object
    
    ' get web page
    Set HTMLDoc = CreateObject("HTMLfile")
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With request
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    ' parse html table
    Dim wb As Workbook, r As Long, c As Long, arr
    Dim tbl As Object, t As Object, tr As Object, td As Object
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set tbl = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("etxtmed")
    
    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No tables found", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If tbl(2) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Table not found", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        Else
            r = tbl(2).Rows.Length
            ReDim arr(1 To r, 1 To 3)
            r = 1
            For Each tr In tbl(2).Rows
               c = 1
               For Each td In tr.Cells
                   arr(r, c) = td.innerText
                   c = c + 1
               Next
               r = r + 1
            Next
        End If
                 
        'copy to sheet
        With wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
            .UsedRange.WrapText = False
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
          
    End If
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tested the code last night and it runs successfully. It seems the website is currently not available and I will test it later. Since I often use IE method and XMLHTTP method is quite new for me, based on what I could learn so far you try to get all elements class named ```etxtmed```. ```tbl(2)``` means the 3rd ```etxtmed``` table. Then you run through all rows and columns of table and store it in a dynamic array. For ```arr(1 To r, 1 To 3)```, does that mean you restricted the columns of the array to 2? Is it possible I change it to ```arr(0 To r, 0 To c)```?

Comment: @SunGuochen The page has nested tables with class etxtmed so I iterated through them and found tbl(2) was the one you wanted. You can have a dymanic array size except the table has merged cells on first and last rows so it's not that easy to determine the max size.